# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C

Tags: php, oracle-11g, php5, oracle-10g

!Saludos¡

Estaba trabajando con PHP Versión 5.4.3 conectada 2 Bases de Datos 
(version Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit ) (version Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit )
Al realizar la actualización a PHP Versión 7.2.1 me arroja el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\conexion\class_conexion.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\conexion\class_conexion.php(28): Conexionbd->conectar() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\conexion\prueba.php(8): Conexionbd->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\conexion\class_conexion.php on line 33

he aquí el archivo class_conexion.php

```
<?php 
class Conexionbd
{   
private $_conexion;
private $_resultado;
private $_servidor;
private $_basedatos;
private $_usuario;
private $_clave;
private $_query;

//funcion asigna variables de config a variables privadas
public function __construct(){
  include("config.php");
  $this->_servidor = $config['servidor'];
  $this->_basedatos = $config['basedatos'];
  $this->_usuario = $config['usuario'];
  $this->_clave = $config['clave'];
  $this->conectar();
 }

//Metoodo con el que me conecto
private function conectar(){
  $this->_conexion  = 
  ($this->_usuario, $this->_clave, $this->_servidor, 'UTF8') or
         trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
  }

//metodo para OCI_PARSE
public function ociParse($query){
 $this->_query = $query;
 $this->_resultado = oci_parse($this->_conexion, $this->_query);
 }

 //EJECUTA EL QUERY 
 public function execute($perror){
 //$this->execute = $execute;
 //$this->_resultado = oci_parse($this->_conexion, $this->_query);
 return oci_execute($this->_resultado) or die(oci_error($this->_conexion)." ( ".$perror." )");
 }

//metodo para buscar.
public function assoc(){
  return oci_fetch_array($this->_resultado, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
}

public function assocAll(){
  oci_fetch_all($this->_resultado, $res);
  return $res;
}

public function rows(){
  return oci_num_rows($this->_resultado);
}

public function close(){
  return oci_close($this->_conexion);
}
}
?>
```

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan dar respecto al tema.

!Saludos¡

Comment: Hola Marcos, si, claro que si, la verdad no entiendo porque con PHP 7.2.1 no me funciona. ¡Help!

Comment: Ahora tengo el problema con DOMPDF... No es compatible con PHP7...
PHP me esta generando muchoooooooossssss problemas... :/

Comment: Si pudiste resolver el problema con `OCI8`, sería una excelente idea que crees una respuesta detallando los pasos que realizaste para llegar a la solución. Por otro lado, si ahora tienes problemas con `DOMPDF`, deberías crear una nueva pregunta, detallando lo mejor posible el error que recibes.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, ya hice una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Conectate como dba y ejecuta: execute dbms_connection_pool.start_pool(); execute dbms_connection_pool.restore_defaults();

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

1. Siempre que conecte Oracle Database, intente utilizar bibliotecas cliente de 32 bits, ya que XAMP PHP está compilado con 32 bits (aunque se tenga 64 bit en el S.O)
2. Descargue Oracle Client desde la página de Oracle; puedes buscar en google "Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)"
3. Pégalo en C:\ instantclient_12_2 y en C:/xamp/php
4. Establezca la ruta a arriba (C:\ instantclient_12_2) en Variable de entorno del sistema (PATH).
5. Luego vaya a C: \ xampp \ php \ php.ini y descomente la extensión = php_oci8_12c.dll
6. Reinicie el XAMP

!Saludos¡

Comment: Solo de curioso, ¿estas seguro que también hay que copiarlo en `C:/xamp/php`?

Comment: Hola Marcos, leí en un foro que sugerían copiar la carpeta del cliente "C:/xamp/php" en la ruta y en la ruta C:\xampp\apache\bin, sin embargo solo la copie en "C:/xamp/php" y funcionó.